# Best way to convert OpenGL immediate mode rendering utility methods to using VBOs?

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, vertex-buffer, utility-method, immediate-mode

I've written for myself a small utility class containing useful methods for rendering lines, quads, cubes, etc. quickly and easily in OpenGL.  Up until now, I've been using almost entirely immediate mode, so I could focus on learning other aspects of OpenGL.  It seems prudent to switch over to using VBOs. However, I want to keep much of the same functionality I've been using, for instance my utility class.  Is there a good method of converting these simple immediate mode calls to a versatile VBO system?

I am using LWJGL.

Comment: This is too snarky to post as an answer, but I really think this is the answer. The best way to convert such code is to design it based on using VBOs. Do it any other inferior way and you will have (comparatively) a monstrosity to maintain.

Comment: Depending on how complicated you want to get, you can reusably wrap the immediate mode command stream in a VBO in < 50 lines of code. `glBegin (...)` is such a beautifully simple thing, with its handful of commands that are allowed inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having converted my own code from begin..end blocks and also taught others, this is what I recommend.

I'm assuming that your utility class is mostly static methods, draw a line from this point to that point.

First step is to have each individual drawing operation create a VBO for each attribute. Replace your glBegin..glEnd block with code that creates an array (actually a ByteBuffer) for each vertex attribute: coordinates, colors, tex coords, etc. After what used to be glEnd, copy the ByteBuffers to the VBOs with glBufferData. Then set up the attributes with chunks of glEnableClientState, glBindBuffer, glVertex|Color|whateverPointer calls. Call glDrawArrays to actually draw something, and finally restore client state and delete the VBOs.

Now, this is not good OpenGL code and is horribly inefficient and wasteful. But it should work, it's fairly straightforward to write, and you can change one method at a time.

And if you don't need to draw very much, well modern GPUs are so fast that maybe you won't care that it's inefficient.

Second step is to start re-using VBOs. Have your class create one VBO for each possible attribute at init time or first use. The drawing code still creates ByteBuffer data arrays and copies them over, but doesn't delete the VBOs.

Third step, if you want to move into OpenGL 4 and are using shaders, would be to replace glVertexPointer with glVertexAttribPointer(0, glColorPointer with glVertexAttribPointer(1, etc. You should also create a Vertex Array Object along with the VBOs at init time. (You'll still have to enable/disable attrib pointers individually depending on whether each draw operation needs colors, tex coords, etc.)

And the last step, which would require changes elsewhere to your program(s), would be to go for 3D "objects" rather than methods. Your utility class would no longer contain drawing methods. Instead you create a line, quad, or cube object and draw that. Each of these objects would (probably) have its own VBOs. This is more work, but really pays off in the common case when a lot of your 3D geometry doesn't change from frame to frame. But again, you can start with the more "wasteful" approach of replacing each method call to draw a line from P1 to P2 with something like l = new Line3D(P1, P2) ; l.draw().

Hope this helps.